# How to fetch the facebook public contents through hashtag using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want fetch the facebook images based on the hashtag using ruby on rails

Comment: can you show the code , which you have?

Comment: i didn't start the work.I have to start the work.So i want to know the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala)** gem. Koala is the most used gem to interact with Facebook: you use it to post, fetch profiles, read and write comments, and so on.